# Monotone increasing sequence of rationals with an irrational limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, real-numbers

I am trying to use rationals in order to approximate irrationals.

Is it possible to construct a monotonically increasing sequence of rationals the limit 
of which is an irrational?

If so, how?

Comment: If I understand correctly, consider $3,\hspace{2px}3.1,\hspace{2px}3.14,\hspace{2px}3.141,\hspace{2px}3.1415,...$

Comment: Of course. Take smaller and smaller neighborhoods around your irrational. In each neighborhood you can pick a rational less than it but as close as you want.

Answer (score 4):

In general, if $x$ is irrational, then
$$
a_n=\frac{\lfloor 2^nx\rfloor}{2^n}<x,
$$
is an increasing ($a_n\le a_{n+1}$) sequence of rationals converging to $x$. Here $\lfloor a \rfloor$ is the integer part of $a$.

**Note.** It is possible to extract a strictly increasing sequence, as all the terms of the sequence are strictly smaller than the limit.

Comment: $\frac{p}{2^n}\le x <\frac{p+1}{2^n}\iff p\le 2^n x<p+1$. Neat.  +1!